# Using symmetry to solve $\iiint_{R}(xy+z^2)dV$ where $R:0\leq z\leq 1-|x|-|y|$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'd really appreciate some help understanding the following solution:

> [image]

I know this fact from Wikipedia: *When the domain of integration is symmetric about the origin with respect to at least one of the variables of integration and the integrand is odd with respect to this variable, the integral is equal to zero, as the integrals over the two halves of the domain have the same absolute value but opposite signs. When the integrand is even with respect to this variable, the integral is equal to twice the integral over one half of the domain, as the integrals over the two halves of the domain are equal.*

I generally tend to struggle with visualising the 3D shape so for the sake of future would prefer not to rely on looking on the one in the solution, but I do know how to draw the region in the $xy$ plane.

> [image]

Will this suffice for understanding the symmetry? My (probably flawed) thinking is this: Since the integrand of $\iiint_{R}xy$ is odd in $x$ and the region in the $xy$ plane as above is clearly symmetric with respect to $x=0$, then this integral is 0. Also $z^2$ is even and the region in the $xy$ plane is symmetric about both the $x$ and $y$ axes (the $xy$ plane?). The solution multiplies by 4 in so I guess we are doubling twice because of the 4 regions but I'm a bit confused as to exactly how I would know to do this.

Comment: Your reasoning is good. In each secction parallel to $xy$-plane there are four regions of equal area and with z taking the same value. You don't need symmetry inasmuch $z$ is constant for each section and goes out when integrating that section. For the $xy$ term, is as you say.

Comment: @RafaBudría Hi, many thanks for your reply! So if a double integral is 0, does this mean that the triple integral involving that double integral must be 0? In other words, if we call the region in the $xy$ plane $D$, is it correct to assume that $$\iint_{D}xy=0 \implies \iiint_{R}xy=\iint_{D}\int_{z=0}^{z=1-x-y}xy\, dz dA =0$$

Comment: @RafaBudría Just another quick question, if you don't mind. I was looking at this link about symmetry (http://www.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/~cleary/math203/symplane.pdf), and it says that $B=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1, x>0\}$ is not symmetric across the $xy$ plane ($z=0$) but if I plug in $-z$ for $z$, you get the same set $B$, which the link previously suggests is how you check something is symmetric? Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure what are you asking. The integral you posed is not zero.

Comment: It is an error. Yu checked it well.

Comment: @RafaBudría What I mean is that we know $\iint_{D}xy=0$ because $xy$ is odd in $x$ and $D$ is symmetric with respect to $x=0$. By saying that $\iiint_{R}xy=0$, aren't we assuming that the double integral is 0 implies that that the triple integral $\iiint_{R}xy$ is also 0?

Comment: Now it's right. I've read $x^2$, that doesn't integrate to zero. With $xy$, yes, the triple vanishes because the double does.

Comment: @RafaBudría Aha that was a typo from me and I edited it. Sorry about the confusion and thanks so much for your help! I've been stuck on this for ages xD

Comment: You are welcome. You are in a good way!